# I have been issued an overlapping Schengen Visa, would there be an issue?

Tags: visas, schengen, legal

I have an existing used Schengen visa from the **21-July-2015 to 20-July-2016** issued by Belgium. I recently applied for a Schengen visa from Germany & was issued a visa from the **19-July-2016 to 18-July-2017**. As you can see, there's an overlap of 19th & 20th of June. Would this cause an issue when I'm traveling? The agents at VFS assured me that this wouldn't be an issue but can someone please confirm?

Comment: Well, "everbody knows" that such overlapping visas cannot even be issued. But I have been unable to find any official rule saying so, despite persistent search in the relevant EU law. Perhaps it's not as absolute as we've been telling ourselves?

Comment: True @HenningMakholm, possibly also something that has recently been introduced? Also to note,there was definitely a slight change in the application process this time - more forms to be filled.

Comment: Since the old visa has already expired, I can't see any possible problem.

Comment: @MichaelHampton there's a mention in the handbook for the processing of visas: http://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf ("the validity of the new visa must complement the current
visa"). However there's no such clause in the relevant law: http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810&from=EN

Comment: @JonathanReez: Good catch. I tried a lot of different search terms in that handbook without finding anything relevant myself.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I presume it's a general *recommendation* for the consulates, not a legal rule. Hence there's no way OP could be in trouble.

Comment: These are not visitors visas, these are some sort of long term visas, as far as I can see from the dates. D perhaps and from two different countries. Perhaps that's why?

Comment: @chx - you can get mutiple-entry visitor visas for periods of year or more. Just each stay has to conform to 90/180

Comment: @HenningMakholm I looked it up a long time ago and also concluded that it was more a recommended practice than an actual rule. As Jonathan already explained, it's mentioned in one of the Commission's *Handbook* but (1) those are not binding and sometimes not followed strictly (cf. the recommendation about grace periods, two-entry visas, duration of stay for visas longer than six months) and (2) the sentence is question is ostensibly only about multiple-entry visas (which is however the most relevant scenario and probably also the case here).

Comment: @chx A short-stay Schengen visa can have a validity period of up to 5 years.

Answer (score 9):

As @HenningMakholm mentions the belief that it's *illegal* or *impossible* to have two overlapping visas is misleading. The [Visa Code](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32009R0810&from=EN) (EU's main law on the Schengen area) mentions nothing about overlapping visas. However the [Handbook for the processing of visa applications](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf) contains the following recommendation:

> A holder of a multiple-entry visa may apply for a new visa before the expiry of the validity of
>   the visa currently held. However, the validity of the new visa must complement the current
>   visa, i.e. a person cannot hold two uniform visas valid for the same period in time.

Note that the rule is for the *consulate*, not for the *applicant*. Hence you cannot be held responsible for the consulate's mistake in issuing the visa correctly. Seeing that the previous visa has already expired you shouldn't have any problems at the border.