# For Germany, can I apply for a long-term visa while holding a short-term one?

Tags: indian-citizens, family, long-stay-visas, schengen-visas

Can I apply for a family reunification visa while holding a visitor visa for Germany?

My appointment for family reunification visa interview is 5th Nov and my tourist visa is valid from 10th Nov.

Comment: Yes, you can.  They might cancel the tourist visa, but there's nothing stopping your application.

Comment: @phoog, if he tells the same truth in both applications there should be little risk of a cancellation, right? That would only happen if information in the family reunion application puts the ties to the home counrty into question.

Comment: @o.m. I don't know.  In many countries they'll cancel a short-term visa if they give you a long-term visa.  I don't know whether Germany is such a country.

Comment: @phoog, that's something else. I think the C visa would be cancelled if a D visa is *granted*, because a D includes a C.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/72204/32134