# Can I have two types of German visa at the same time?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I have a German business visa, but soon I will have new type of visa (family visa). Is it possible to have both visas at the same time, or will the German embassy will cancel the business visa?

Comment: What is a "Family visa"? Do you want the visas to overlap?

Comment: Also there is nothing such as a "German business visa" -- you probably have a _uniform short-stay Schengen visa_ (type C).

Comment: They will cancel the more junior visa.

Answer (score 5):

The [Handbook for the processing of visa applications](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf) (an official document with a list of guidances for Schengen consulates) contains the following recommendation:

> A holder of a multiple-entry visa may apply for a new visa before the expiry of the validity of
>   the visa currently held. However, the validity of the new visa must complement the current
>   visa, i.e. a person cannot hold two uniform visas valid for the same period in time.

Therefore the answer is that you cannot have two visas for the same time period - either the second visa will start after the first one or the first one will be cancelled. However note that consulates [sometimes make mistakes](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/72204/i-have-been-issued-an-overlapping-schengen-visa-would-there-be-an-issue) with this rule, so it's technically possible for a person to have overlapping visas, if the consulate makes an error.